# Tell iOS to not resize SKNode animated texture?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm coding a game for iOS with Swift.

The game is being initialized with an array of textures. I use those textures in animation.

I create an `SKNode` each time with different size:

```
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: nodeTextures[0])
node.size = size; //from func argument
node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever
(SKAction.animateWithTextures
(nodeTextures, timePerFrame: 0.05, resize: false, restore: false)))
```

Node rendered with resized texture.

Can I somehow tell iOS to not resize texture? If yes can I somehow define origin coordinate of texture in SKNode?

Comment: Use `node.xScale` and `node.yScale` to adjust the image scale and make it smaller.  If you are using retina @2x images, use `node.xScale = 0.5` and `node.yScale = 0.5`.

Comment: Read carefully: i do not need to rescale image. The problem is in scaling. I need to disable scale, when i resize SKNode.

Comment: Are you sure it is resizing? If lets say you set the size to 50 x 50 and you pass in a texture of 25 x 50 it is going to look really bad because it is going to stretch it.  It isn't resizing it is staying at the 50 x 50.  Setting resize to false only looks good if the textures are all the same size. Without seeing the result I would guess you want a combo of setting the scale and leaving resize to true. If that makes sense I could help with how to calculate the scale you need.

Comment: Im sure its resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a child node with the textures and the animation.  Call `node.addChild(textureNode)` to make it a child.  Then run the action on that child node, which will always be in the same position as `node`, but not change `node`'s size.  Something like this:

```
let node = SKSpriteNode()
node.size = size; //from func argument
// Create texture node to hold the texture
let textureNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nodeTextures[0])
node.addChild(textureNode)
textureNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever
(SKAction.animateWithTextures
(nodeTextures, timePerFrame: 0.05, resize: false, restore: false)))
```

This allows you to adjust `node`'s size later without rescaling the images in `textureNode`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the SpriteKit '`animate`' resizing function. If you put "`false`" what will you see is only the real animation stretched to fill inside your node parent. So , you need to put the '`resize`' parameter to **true** and you animation will be corrected to it's original size.

Using your code, you can simply scale your animation to fit inside your context:

```
if let firstTexture = nodeTextures.first {
   let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstTexture, size:size)
   let scaledAction = SKAction.scale(to: (node.size.height/firstTexture.size().height),duration:0.01)
   node.run(SKAction.repeatActionForever
(SKAction.sequence([scaledAction,SKAction.animate(nodeTextures, timePerFrame: 0.05, resize: true, restore: false)])))
}
```